# angular2: origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: django, angular

I have a django backend and I have enabled Cross origin requests as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ..
    'corsheaders',

]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

I haven't implemented any authentication. I simply am trying to hit an API endpoint and trying to fetch data on my Angular2 frontend.

I have implemented a session based cart in Django backend which stores my products (https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton). When I hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shopping-cart/show/ through my browsable api it gives me

```
{"1":{"product_pk":1,"price":"23000.00000","quantity":3},"2":{"product_pk":2,"price":"34000.00000","quantity":7},"4":{"product_pk":4,"price":"450.00000","quantity":1}}
```

However when I try to hit the same url from my Angular2 service: it throws me error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shopping-cart/show/. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

My service call is as follows:

```
 private myUrl: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shopping-cart/'
    showCart(){

            return this.http.get(this.myUrl + 'show' + '/', {withCredentials:true})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())

        }
```

Note: If I remove {withCredentials:true} then it does not send sessionid or csrftoken and returns {} but the error vanishes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my Django settings I had to add:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS= True
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if you use `withCredentials: true` you can't use `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but need `http://localhost:3000` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *`
>   The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource. The browser must enforce this. For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

Comment: Okay, where and how do I add this in my request?

Comment: There is nothing to do on the request. The browser expects this in the resposne header in the response from the server. I don't know Django and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You middleware order problem. Try this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]
```

Note that CorsMiddleware needs to come before Django's CommonMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular2 integrated proxy.

1. create proxy.conf.json file
2. in proxy.conf write:

   {
     "/api/shopping-cart/": {
       "target": "http://localhost:8000",
       "secure": false
     }
   }
3. in your package.json change "start" script to:
       "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
4. run "npm start" in your command line